# Преобразовать Json в List<MyClass>

Tags: c#, json, list, deserialize

**Мой класс:**

```
public class MyModel
{
    [DeserializeAs(Name = "brand")]
    public string Brand { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "number")]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "fix")]
    public string Fix { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DeserializeAs(Name = "availability")]
    public int Availability { get; set; }
}
```

**Я делаю запрос (По выполнению запроса я получаю пустой лист):**

```
var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<List<MyModel>>(request);
```

**Приходящий Json выглядит следующим образом:**

```
{
    "BB Brand655569":{
        "availability":1,"brand":"BB Brand","description":"","number":"655569","fix":"655569"
    },
    "AUG655569":{
        "availability":1,"brand":"AUG","description":"Он самый","number":"655569","fix":"655569"
    },
    "ABC655569":{
        "availability":1,"brand":"ABC","description":"","number":"655569","fix":"655569"
    },
    "Alcanaft655569":{
        "availability":1,"brand":"Alcanaft","description":"600ММ/24 all day","number":"655569","fix":"655569"
    },
    "Eragon655569":{
        "availability":1,"brand":"Eragon","description":"","number":"655569","fix":"655569"
    },
}
```

Как сделать так что бы данный Json преобразовывался в список с которым можно работать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам приходит не список, а словарь. Каждому ключу соответствует один объект. Попробуйте так

```
var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<Dictionary<string, MyModel>>(request);
```

Если нужен именно список, воспользуйтесь свойством `response.Values`

Comment: Действительно, это оказался словарь, спасибо большое